# Access code in a View via reflection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reflection

I have an HtmlHelper CmsEntry that is used like this

```
<%= Html.CmsEntry("stores.buyourstuff")%>
```

This helper is used lots of times and I want to generate a list of all views that contain this helper.

The list should contain the Viewname and the key ("stores.buyourstuff").

Is there a tool or some sample code that already does this?

Answer (score 0):

Look at official site.

[Creating Custom HTML Helpers : The Official Microsoft ASP.NET Site](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-09-cs.aspx)

HtmlHelper have ViewContext property. It can access ViewData and TempData.

Comment: I allready have the helper. I need a list that contains every occurence of the helper in the project.